# Using Date formatter

Tags: ios, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have an issue with date Formatter.

I have Two string. one string contains date in form of MM/dd/yyyy; and second string contains time in form of hh:mm a.

Now i want to concatenate this two strings and want output as a new strings in form of 
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.

I have tried following but unfortunately it doesn't work more.

```
-(NSString *)ConcateDateAndTime:(NSString *)date Time:(NSString *)time{

    date = [date stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@",time];



    NSDateFormatter *formater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formater setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa"];

    NSDate *dt = [NSDate date];
    dt = [formater dateFromString:date];

    NSDateFormatter *formater1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

    NSString *temp;
    temp = [formater1 stringFromDate:dt];

    return temp;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead as you've also got a memory leak:

```
-(NSString *)ConcateDateAndTime:(NSString *)date Time:(NSString *)time{

    date = [date stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@",time];

    NSDateFormatter *formater = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [formater setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa"];

    NSDate *dt = [formater dateFromString:date];

    [formater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

    return [formater stringFromDate:dt];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the second `[formater setDateFormat]` call to use **formater1**.

Comment: I can't believe I set up a whole project to figure this out and as soon as the debugger gets there, I come back and you've answered. +1

Comment: Right on David, I also had to create a Window based project (since it's the one I'm most familiar with) just to try it out. :) Thanks Carl and David for pointing out the memory leak issue.

Comment: @David Thanks for the help and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Thanks Paul David and Carl, i will also take care of leaks.